# infinite solutions of $x'=f(\frac{x}{t})$ tangents to $\phi(t)=rt$ in origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**: Be $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ class $C^1$ and $f(r)=r$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $f'(r)>1$ then exist a infinite solutions of $x'=f(\frac{x}{t})$ tangents to $\phi(t)=rt$ in origin.

Comment: I can not solve this problem. This is very important for the teacher.

Comment: If $f(r)=r$, then $f'(r)=1$.